# Improving Verilog Code

Tags: verilog, design, alu

I've written an 8-bit shifter in verilog

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

/* this is a very simple example of a 8 bit shift */
/* the shift amount is always 1 */
/* sw = 0 means left shift while sw = 1 means right shift */
/* this is an example of a combinational ciruit */

module shifter_8bit(input [7:0] A,
                    input sw,
                    output reg [7:0] B);

    /* whenever the value of any of the input signal changes, we want the system to act */
    /* therefore this would go into an always block */
    always @(A, sw)
        begin
            /* because we are providing support for both LS as well as RS, we need a 2-1 MUX */
            case(sw)
                /* As sw is a one bit, we can have only two possibilities */
                1'b0:
                    /* left shift A by 1 */
                    begin
                        B[7] = A[6];
                        B[6] = A[5];
                        B[5] = A[4];
                        B[4] = A[3];
                        B[3] = A[2];
                        B[2] = A[1];
                        B[1] = A[0];
                        B[0] = 0;
                    end
                1'b1:
                    /* right shift A by 1 */
                    begin
                        B[7] = 0;
                        B[6] = A[7];
                        B[5] = A[6];
                        B[4] = A[5];
                        B[3] = A[4];
                        B[2] = A[3];
                        B[1] = A[2];
                        B[0] = A[1];
                    end
            endcase
        end
endmodule
```

I come from a C background, and all I'm interested in is providing and using abstraction, which clearly lacks in this module. Although this does synthesize correctly, it isn't much attractive to the eye. I have created a 4-bit shifter module as well, and wish to use them. However whenever I try to use them in the always block, it gives me a problem.

Is there any way by which I can modify the code I've written and use the 4-bit shifter module, and not effect the overall synthesis? In general, are there any rules I should go by to get quality verilog code, or is it all about the synthesis?

Best, 
Bilal

Comment: I would first check requirements. Inputs are 8-bit register (8 data wires), and SW switch identifies direction. Then you want to have B 8-bit width as output. What exactly you want to get as output, and, most importantly - *when*? IMHO your current circuit (note - it is not *code* but *circuit*) will only output B=A<<1 or B=A>>1. Is it what you want to get?

Comment: That is exactly what I want, but I don't want to use built in operators like << or >> to achieve this. I want to encapsulate everything that being done inside the case statement in other modules I've created(like the 4-bit shifter). Is it possible to use such abstraction in verilog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wire [7:0] B = sw ? { 1'b0, A[7:1] } : { A[6:0], 1'b0 };
```

I do not think you need always block for this combinatorial circuit.

Comment: That is a reasonable solution. But what if I want to use modules inside always block? Like for a 16-bit adder, you always use 4-bit adders and for 4-bit adder, you always use 1-bit adders. This is only one example.

Comment: This is not programming, you do not need to have something within the *perceived code* to make it continuously running. In the case of my example, you put it inside the module, and it always "runs" appropriately as involved input and control lines change. There're other peculiarities like "order of execution" in always block, but in your case task is simple and I do not think it is being involved. That's why I asked what you want to get in comment to your question. In addition, if you will want strobed shift register, you will have to have always block.

Comment: You cannot use modules in an always block.

Comment: I think @BilalWasim may not understand whole concept on its high level. It is very easy to get to Verilog after C, but this actually creates a trap by thinking that Verilog "runs" the same way as C. Bilal, you need to read some basic information about HDL, its structure and how it is being implemented into circuits on the lowest level.

Comment: I think I'm mixing up the gate-level implementation with the data flow model. I want to use both of them, but that's not possible? Is this correct @Anonymous

Comment: It is possible. Look here for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751979/difference-between-behavioral-and-dataflow-in-verilog/28759581#28759581. The functional result is the same. I would compare them in C as "if (condition) { a=b; } else  { a=c; }" and "a=condition?b:c". Which one you prefer, and which one takes less characters and reads better? Plus, as I said before, with `always` blocks there's such thing as *order of execution* which allows same reg to be assigned different values throughout the listing within always block defining which value will be at the output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always do shifts like so:

```
B = {A[6:0], 1'b0};
```

and

```
B = {1'b0, A[7:1]};
```

You can't instantiate modules inside of always blocks; you'll need to post the code for your 4 bit shifter to get a good answer.  However, it is possible to make parametrized modules where you can specify the width when you instantiate it, something like this:

```
module shift_lr #
(
    parameter WIDTH = 8
)
(
    input  wire [WIDTH-1:0] din;
    input  wire             shift_dir;
    output wire [WIDTH-1:0] dout;
);

assign dout = shift_dir ? {1'b0, din[WIDTH-1:1]} : {din[WIDTH-2:0], 1'b0};

endmodule


shift_lr #(
    .WIDTH(4)
)
shift_lr_4_inst (
    .din(...),
    .shift_dir(...),
    .dout(...)
);
```

Comment: This is not just about the shifts. I want to develop a way of thinking about verilog design, and this doesn't do that for me.